# Difference between tilde expansion in RStudio and R

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

On (my install of) RStudio on Windows `path.expand("~")` returns "C:/Users/myusername/Documents".  However `RScript -e path.expand('~')` from the command line returns "C:\Users\myusername" (the same from the R REPL).  This makes scripts that use a tilde and work in one environment fail in the other.  A possible fix is to execute `set R_USER=C:\Users\myusername\Documents` before running the script from the command line, but this seems like a kludge; it also might trip up other users of my script unless I warn them to set `R_USER`.  I also tried adding an entry to `~/.Renviron` but that seemed to cause the 'Source' button in RStudio to fail.

What is the best way to make RStudio and R agree on how to expand tilde?

Comment: Could it be that RStudio uses a different version of R?

Comment: @krlmlr Good point.  However it looks like both use the same version of R.  `sessionInfo()` in both cases produces `R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1`.

Comment: Look at `Sys.getenv("R_USER")` in both `Rscript` and RStudio. Set it explicitly in `.Renviron`

Comment: I would say, don't rely on expansion, never. Use a fixed path (maybe asking the user) or an environment variable (but again this may change depending on how the program is called)

Comment: @Tensibai I think not relying on tilde expansion makes sense.  I'll answer my question with a fleshed-out version of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Tensibai, not relying on tilde-expansion might be the best solution.  Instead I'm using the following function:

```
Home <- function() {
  # Returns a string with the user's home directory
  #
  # Serves as a replacement for "~", and works both in RStudio and RScript.
  #
  # Returns:
  #   On Windows returns C:/Users/<username>, where <username> is the current user's username.

  normalizePath(file.path(Sys.getenv("HOMEDRIVE"), Sys.getenv("HOMEPATH")), winslash = .Platform$file.sep)
}
```

It should be straightforward to extend this to work cross-platform.